# 2 is not a valid direct i/o file descriptor resources php

Tags: php

We are trying to read and write from RFID using php, currenctly we are able to set things such as baudrate and pirity but unable to write to RFID nor read from RFID

Below is my php code :

```
if (strtoupper(substr(PHP_OS, 0, 3)) === 'WIN') 
{ 
    echo "hi Windows/n";
    $bbSerialPort = dio_open($portName, O_RDWR);

    if($bbSerialPort){
        dio_close($bbSerialPort);
    }

    exec("mode {$portName} baud={$baudRate} data={$bits} stop={$spotBit} parity=n xon=on");
    $bbSerialPort;
    echo '/nsuccessfull exec';
} 

if(!$bbSerialPort)
{
    echoFlush( "Could not open Serial port {$portName} ");
    exit;
}

$dataToReboot = pack("H*","0205F08A7E");
$bytesSent    = dio_write($bbSerialPort, $dataToReboot );

$runForSeconds = new DateInterval("PT5S"); //5 seconds
$endTime = (new DateTime())->add($runForSeconds);
echoFlush(  "Waiting for {$runForSeconds->format('%S')} seconds to recieve data on serial port" );

while (new DateTime() < $endTime) {

    $data = dio_read($bbSerialPort, 256); //this is a blocking call
    echo "<br>"."number";
    if ($data) {
        echoFlush(  "Data Recieved: ". $data );

    }
}
echoFlush(  "Closing Port" );

dio_close($bbSerialPort);
```

Comment: Are you using any library?

Comment: @GauravDave nope we only using php Direct IO only

Answer (score 1):

You're calling `dio_close` on `$bbSerialPort` at the top of the script. Meaning, you're closing the connection to the RFID. You can't send it a message after closing the connection.